# How-to: Setup Azure Push Notification with Client SDK v3.1.0 and Server SDK v2.0.0 using a CustomAuthController

Tags: azure-mobile-services

Since a few days the new Azure Server and Client SDK are available. I had that issue with the App Service Push https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/issues/170#issuecomment-262656329 in last November 2016.

After reading the release blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/01/10/azure-mobile-apps-net-sdk-releases/ I can now see that the current
way to register for push notification is **deprecated**.

Can you please give me detailed instructions what I have to change to use the new App Service Push?

The previous problem was that the

> _UserId (SID)

Tag was **not properly included** in the push notification installation. The _UserId had the MD5 hash of the NameIdentifier instead of the clients unique Id I passed to the CustomAuthController. But I need my clients unique Id afterwards for targeted push notifications to clients utilizing the

> _UserId=client-unique-id

Here is my current code in Android:

```
protected override void OnRegistered(Context context, string registrationId)
    {
        Log.Verbose("PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver", "GCM Registered: " + registrationId);
        App.NotificationHubInstallationId = registrationId;

        //await RegisterForPushNotifications(OfflineSyncStoreManager.Instance.MobileAppClient, MainActivity.CurrentActivity);

        MainActivity.CurrentActivity.RunOnUiThread(async () =>
        {
            if (GcmClient.IsRegistered(context))
            {
                try
                {
                    var pushHub = OfflineSyncStoreManager.Instance.MobileAppClient.GetPush();
                    const string templateBodyGcm = "{\"data\":{\"message\":\"$(messageParam)\"}}";

                    var templates = new JObject
                    {
                        ["genericMessage"] = new JObject
                        {
                            {"body", templateBodyGcm}
                        }
                    };

                    //NOTE: Unregister any previous NotificationHub Installation of the TruckerApp on that device
                    await pushHub.UnregisterAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                    //NOTE_ Register the TruckerApp for Push Notification in the backend.
                    await pushHub.RegisterAsync(registrationId, templates).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    MetricsManager.TrackEvent($"PushNotificationHub-{OfflineSyncStoreManager.Instance.MobileAppClient.CurrentUser.UserId}",
                        new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                            {"NotificationHubInstallationId", registrationId}
                        },
                        new Dictionary<string, double>());


                    Log.Info("Push Installation Id", App.NotificationHubInstallationId);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    await MetricsManagerHelper.Instance.SendErrorToApplicationInsightsAsync($"PushNotificationHub Registration failed for reason: {ex.Message}");
                    DialogNotify("AZURE PUSH Registierungsfehler", "Pushmeldungen sind derzeit nicht verfügbar. " + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                                                                   "Um neue Aufträge auf Ihr Handy zu übertragen ziehen " +
                                                                   "Sie bitte in der Truck Auftrag Übericht (hier!) " +
                                                                   "mit dem Finger von OBEN -> nach -> UNTEN." +
                                                                   Environment.NewLine +
                                                                   Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await MetricsManagerHelper.Instance.SendErrorToApplicationInsightsAsync("GCM/FCM Client is not registered at Google");
                DialogNotify("GCM/FCM Push Registrierungsfehler", "Sei konnten nicht beim Google Cloud Messaging angemeldet werden. " +
                                                                  "Versuchen Sie bitte ein ReLogin oder um neue Aufträge " +
                                                                  "auf Ihr Handy zu übertragen, ziehen " +
                                                                  "Sie bitte in der Truck Auftrag Übericht (hier!) " +
                                                                  "mit dem Finger von OBEN -> nach -> UNTEN." +
                                                                  Environment.NewLine +
                                                                  Environment.NewLine);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my current code in iOS:

```
// We've successfully registered with the Apple notification service, or in our case Azure
    public override async void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        try
        {
            const string templateBodyApns = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"$(messageParam)\"}}";

            JObject templates = new JObject();
            templates["genericMessage"] = new JObject
            {
                {"body", templateBodyApns}
            };

            // Register for push with your mobile app
            Push push = OfflineSyncStoreManager.Instance.MobileAppClient.GetPush();
            await push.RegisterAsync(deviceToken, templates);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            UIAlertView avAlert = new UIAlertView("AZURE PUSH Registierungsfehler",
                "Pushmeldungen sind derzeit nicht verfügbar. " + 
                Environment.NewLine + 
                Environment.NewLine +
                "Um neue Aufträge auf Ihr Handy zu übertragen ziehen " +
                "Sie bitte in der Truck Auftrag Übericht (hier!) " +
                "mit dem Finger von OBEN -> nach -> UNTEN." +
                Environment.NewLine +
                Environment.NewLine,
                null,
                "OK",
                null);
            avAlert.Show();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance,

Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One save way is to use the Azure Mobile Client installationId, persist it in your backend and use that Id for targeted push notifications to that individual client. Instead sending the push notification to `_UserId:your-userid` post to `$installationId:your-clients-zumo-client-id`

But that requires you to store the `installationId` in your backend SQL Server or other cache (e.g. Redis)

A better solution is to follow both links below:

General App Service Push Notification Installations [ZUMO Book](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter5/concepts/)

and for custom push notification Tags that [Custom Tag Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/writingdata_services/2016/01/22/adding-push-notification-tags-from-an-azure-mobile-apps-client/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to unregister and then register - a simple register will do it.

Check out chapter 5 of the book - http://aka.ms/zumobook - there is code within the chapter for each type of push registration that covers the Installation method (where you specify tags and templates together).  You can then specify the SID explicitly by constructing a tag that is suitable for your needs.

Comment: In my CustomAuthController I set the IMEI (a unique client ID) to the Sub like that : new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, imei). Until now that value was automatically set in the PNS Installation in the **_UserId** Tag. Is it still the same with the new SDK or please specify what I have to specify to achieve the same goal. Thanks!

Comment: I think the solution to my case is an Automatically added Tag but how can I automatically add the JWT Sub as Tag ?

Comment: I mean the syntax. Is it auto:$(jwt.sub) ?

Comment: The syntax is within the App Service Push record.  You want something like $(aad.nameidentifier) - see the output of /.auth/me - the construction is $(<provider>.<claim>)

Comment: There is no /.auth/me endpoint in a CustomAuthController! Please answer my comments from above

Comment: If you are using a CustomAuthController, then you also need a custom push registration controller.  This would be a custom API that you call that constructs the appropriate Notification Hubs Installation and called the createOrUpdateInstallation method on Notification Hubs.  Once you go custom, you have to go custom everywhere.